# Lucida calligraphy font not working wordpress site in android chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

I have an wordpress website where in am using lucida calligraphy font for some headings.

I have added them in additional css section using font family attribute for the respective class. This is working fine in desktop , laptop browsers.

But it's not working in mobile chrome android.

Awaiting your reply.

Comment: Please attach your code that you have used to undertake this function. It may assist in understanding and providing a solution.

Comment: .font-custom1{
 font-family:'Lucida Calligraphy'!important;
 }

Comment: .font-custom1{ font-family:'Lucida Calligraphy'!important; }     I have also placed .ttf font in side wp-content/themes/mytheme/fonts/ folder and tried giving the url as well . Even that didnt work.

Comment: Have you attempted to clear your cache or inspect the page (PC browser, mimicking smart phone) to see if it shows? Cache is always one to keep an eye on.

Comment: i tried to mimick user developer tools in various smart phones mode.. it works fine there. but not in android phone browser

Comment: Search/Check the code vs compatibility with the browser in question. Again try incognito mode or clear the cache/delete history and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You have stated it works in developer tools, there for:

1. Clear the cache/delete history and/or try incognito mode.
2. Check the compatibility of the code with the browser in question to see if it is compatible.
3. Attempt to view the website on a phone that has not previously seen the website to get a fresh view.
4. If you are enquing the script, make sure that you are not using a version in the line to prevent old versions being viewed. You can overcome this by setting the version to `date("His")` or similar.